# Using API to change settings in jquery-steps

Tags: jquery-steps

How do I change the settings in query-steps using the API? I'm trying enable all the steps if I am in an Edit mode for a form. I tried using:

```
var wizard = $("#wizard").steps();

   wizard.steps({
     enableAllSteps: true
   });
```

Apparently this isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you just need to do this:

```
$("#wizard").steps({
enableAllSteps: true
});
```

Comment: That was what I thought to begin with. But I get an "Error: One or more corresponding step titles are missing".

Comment: This is a guess: Do you have a mismatch between the number of fieldsets and titles?    You can define what which tag you use for titles and body... headerTag: "h3", bodyTag: "fieldset",

Comment: When I first initialize the wizard with $("#wizard").steps(), if I'm not mistaken, it uses the default settings. Later on in the process, I want to change one of the settings. Do I need to define all the tiles and tags again even though it is only one setting that I wanted changed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I find a partion, You can destroy and build again

```
function updateWizard() {
    if (started == "NotStarted") {
        stepsWizard = stepsWizard.steps("destroy");
        stepsWizard = $("#wizard").steps({
            enablePagination: false
        });
    }
    else {
        stepsWizard.step("destroy");
        stepsWizard = $("#wizard").steps({
            enablePagination: true
        });
    }
}
```